# slider that changes according to image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have some images with different dimensions. I want a slider that changes according to the user's device's screen size.

Desktop users should see 4 slides.

Tablet users should see 2 slides.

Mobile Users should see only a single image.

Is there a way of doing this? If yes, then please tell me.

Comment: unless you are using adaptive templates with some sort of machine type detection, the best way would be to use a responsive slider that will display certain amounts of slides based on screen width

Comment: can you give me some article or some sort of guidance please